# Is there a difference between "sudo apt-get install cuda" and "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit"?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

Using `sudo apt-get install cuda` updates my NVIDIA drivers and my screen stops working. (GeForce GTX 660M; Ubuntu 14.04; CUDA 6.5). I was wondering if using`sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` would help? What is the difference between the two ? I was hoping that the later only installs the toolkit and doesn't change my drivers.
I am sorry if this question seems trivial. I am new to Ubuntu. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For future reference you can confirm the existence of packages as well as get details regarding them by utilizing http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "difference" is that there does not exist any package with the name `cuda`, so you can not install it - the package `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` though does exist (see the explanation below) :

```
apt policy cuda
N: Unable to locate package cuda  

apt policy nvidia-cuda-toolkit  
nvidia-cuda-toolkit:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.44-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     8.0.44-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

The **Compute Unified Device Architecture** (CUDA) enables NVIDIA
graphics processing units (GPUs) to be used for massively parallel
general purpose computation. `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` contains the nvcc compiler and other tools needed for building CUDA applications. Learn more about the details on the official NVIDIA Accelerated Computing Portal -> [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)